# How to remove "..." from my array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string

In my calculator app I ran into a problem where I want `...` to show in my array but only when the if statement for `resultIsPending` is true. Then after that I want the `...` to be deleted. How can I do this in Swift? Here is the code of my ViewController.swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sequence: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

var userInTheMiddleOfTyping = false

var resultIsPending:Bool = false



var elements = [String]()
//var sequenceArray:Array = []
@IBAction func clear(_ sender: Any) {
    display.text = " "
    elements.removeAll()
    elements = elements.filter{$0 != "\(String(describing: display.text))"}
    sequence.text = elements.joined()


}



override func viewDidLoad() {



}

@IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let digit = sender.currentTitle!

    elements.append(digit)

    combineToMakeOperationHistory()



    if userInTheMiddleOfTyping{

            let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display!.text!

            display!.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit


        } else {
            display!.text = digit

            userInTheMiddleOfTyping = true

        }


}

var displayValue: Double{
    get{
        return Double(display.text!)!

    }
    set{
        display.text = String(newValue)
    }
}

private var brain = CalculatorBrain()

@IBAction func performOperation(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let perSender = sender.currentTitle!

    elements.append(perSender)

    combineToMakeOperationHistory()

    if perSender == "+" || perSender == "÷" || perSender == "×" || perSender == "-" || perSender == "^"{

        resultIsPending = true



    }
    if userInTheMiddleOfTyping{
        brain.setOperand(displayValue)
        userInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
    }



    userInTheMiddleOfTyping = false

    if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle{

        brain.performOperation(mathematicalSymbol)
    }
    if brain.result != nil{
        displayValue = brain.result!
    }
}

func combineToMakeOperationHistory() {

         if resultIsPending{ // this is the if statement
        elements.append("...") 
         }else if resultIsPending == false{

    }
    sequence.text = elements.joined()

}
```

Comment: Why do you create a `String` from a `String` in the filter closure?

Comment: @vadian XCode suggested it to remove a warning

Comment: Why do you even add `...` to the array? Wouldn't it be easier to append it dynamically to `sequence.text` instead of appending it to the array?

Comment: Of course – because the text property is optional – but since you just set `display.text` to a space character you can safely unwrap the optional or simply write `{$0 != " "}`

Comment: `display.text` changes throughout the code

Comment: @Sulthan what do you mean by this?

Comment: Two lines before the filter line you set `display.text` clearly to a space character.

Comment: @Sulthan can you put as an answer

Comment: @vadian `display.text` is based on a UILabel. It is only set to " " because the clear button is pressed in that action.

Comment: You don't understand. Nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your elements array and remove the `"..."`.

```
elements = elements.filter({ $0 != "..." })
```

Whenever you want to remove the occurrence of a `String value`.

Comment: Now there aren't any errors but it doesn't delete the `...` from the array even though it should

Comment: If your `elements` array contains "..." it will be deleted with the filter code and then  you just use your elements array after the filter.

Answer (score 0):

you can uses something like hat

```
var resultIsPending:Bool = false{
    didSet(isPending) {
        if isPending {
            elements.append("...")
        } else {
            elements.dropLast()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't combine data that are not of the same type. There is no reason to put `...` into the array of elements:

```
func combineToMakeOperationHistory() {
    var sequenceText: String = elements.joined()

    if (resultIsPending) {
       sequenceText += "..."
    }

    sequence.text = sequenceText
}
```

Since we are not appending `...` to the array, we don't have to remove it.

Comment: but then `...` can never be removed

Comment: @KrishMehra To remove it you only need to set `resultIsPending = false` and call this method again. Or better, you can make the method to be called  automatically `var resultsIsPending: Bool = false { didSet { self.combineToMakeOperationHistory() } }`